# last -t in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm a little bit surprised on Ubuntu and Cent OS, the `last -t` actually behaves as showing logins `up till` the time specified, as opposed to `as of` the time specified as stated in its man page.

Here is what the man page on Ubuntu says:

```
-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
          Display the state of logins as of the specified time. This is useful, e.g., to determine easily who was logged
          in at a particular time -- specify that time with -t and look for "still logged in”.
```

However, the actually behavior looks something like this:

```
# last -F -t 20150107000000 | grep pts
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 18:39:05 2015 - Tue Jan 6 18:40:34 2015 (00:01)
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 18:37:24 2015 - Tue Jan 6 18:37:41 2015 (00:00)
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 16:42:33 2015 - Tue Jan 6 16:43:49 2015 (00:01)
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 13:03:26 2015 - Tue Jan 6 13:07:02 2015 (00:03)
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 09:03:24 2015 - Tue Jan 6 09:03:54 2015 (00:00)
root pts/2 jp001.solidtunne Tue Jan 6 04:53:54 2015 - Tue Jan 6 04:54:07 2015 (00:00)
root pts/4 sf003.solidtunne Fri Jan 2 15:23:12 2015 - Fri Jan 2 15:23:51 2015 (00:00)
root pts/0 hk000.solidtunne Thu Jan 1 16:40:55 2015 - Thu Jan 1 16:41:21 2015 (00:00)
root pts/2 hk000.solidtunne Thu Jan 1 15:41:52 2015 - Thu Jan 1 15:42:02 2015 (00:00)
root pts/4 hk000.solidtunne Thu Jan 1 11:24:56 2015 - Thu Jan 1 13:40:40 2015 (02:15)
root pts/4 hk000.solidtunne Thu Jan 1 11:24:34 2015 - Thu Jan 1 11:24:48 2015 (00:00)
root pts/0 hk000.solidtunne Thu Jan 1 08:31:13 2015 - Thu Jan 1 08:31:25 2015 (00:00)
```

The current date is as follows:

```
# date
Thu Jan 8 08:12:32 UTC 2015
```

And Ubuntu version:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Kernel:

```
# uname -a
Linux install 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have opened a bug in Ubuntu's bug system: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1408605 . However, it seems people are not interested in this bug, and I barely got any information about this bug from Google. I am now confused, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve by downloading the last.c. Go to line 753, change the line from:

```
if (until && until < ut.ut_time)
  continue;
```

to

```
if (until && until > ut.ut_time)
  continue;
```

then recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bug is simply a documentation bug.

Ubuntu 14.10's version of `util-linux` (which is where `last` comes from) is 2.25

Fedora 21's version of `util-linux` is also 2.25.

The `man` page for `last` on Fedora states:

```
   -t, --until time
          Display the state of logins until the specified time.
```

which is what you get as the actual behaviour.

I suggest you raise a bug against `util-linux` on Ubuntu (or Debian) and CentOS for the `man` page.

Comment: It would be sad if this is a documentation bug, because I think `as of` is more, at least equally useful than 'until'. Actually I need to get the most recent login items from this list. If this is the case, there seems to be no easy way to get a list of the most recent login items.